# How to select coresponding drop down box when selecting this.value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to work out a sum and VAT sum from a series of text boxes. The sum part works fine, but it's the VAT part that is proving difficult. In order to add the value to the VAT sum I first need to check if the sum can be added to the VAT total by means of a drop down box. The code used for this so far is:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class="costing" id="ko_unique_3" name="ko_unique_3" /> 
Vat : <select class="vat">
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
</select><br /><br />

<input type="text" class="costing" id="ko_unique_4" name="ko_unique_4" />
Vat : <select class="vat">
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
</select><br /><br />

<input type="text" class="costing" id="ko_unique_5" name="ko_unique_5" />
Vat : <select class="vat">
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
</select><br /><br /><br />

Sum:<br />
<input type="text" id="sum" name="sum" /><br /><br />

VATable Sum:<br />
<input type="text" id="vatableSum" name="vatableSum" />
```

JQuery:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$('.costing').live('keyup', function(e) {
var sum = 0;
var VATSum = 0;
$('.costing').each(function(){
    if (this.value == '') {
       sum += 0;
       VATSum += 0;
    }
    else if {
       sum += parseFloat(this.value);
       VATSum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
    else {
       sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }
});
$('#sum').val(sum);
});
});
```

It is this part:

```
else if {
           sum += parseFloat(this.value);
           VATSum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
```

that I need to figure out what parameters search for the corresponding Yes/No value for the VAT, but that stage the only this.value I can access is the one from the costing box. I need to find a way to tie that costing box to the VAT drop down so they can be awarw of each other.

Hope that makes sense! I can clarify if not, I also have a JS fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/W3R3W0LF666/mKq7u/)

Comment: `$(this).next('.vat').val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either give your corresponding dropdowns a name like ko_unique_4_dropdown and then acces via:

```
$('#'+this.attr('name')+'_dropdown').value
```

Or you can set a data attribute on your input with an ID like this:

```
<input type="text" data-dropdown="dropdown_1" />
<select id="dropdown_1"></select>
```

And access like this:

```
$('#'+this.attr('data-dropdown')).value
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this would have worked if I wasn't dynamically creating the control, but I only had control of the 'class' property.

Comment: You could do it with classes too if you can make the class unique.